# Fading overlay through FrameLayout foreground with specified Rect that cuts out a section of the fade

Tags: java, android, xamarin, drawable, android-framelayout

Goal: A highlighted section of an image (the image covers the whole screen). The rest of the screen needs to be faded out.

[Example](http://oi61.tinypic.com/35kpffq.jpg)

So far I've got the fading working using the foreground of a FrameLayout and placing the image as the background of a RelativeLayout within the FrameLayout. The solution I'm thinking is that I need to create 2 Drawables and merge them into one that FrameLayout Foreground can consume.

I've also been reading a bit up on PorterDuff, but I think that may be overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.

The fade functionality is working fine, but the source of the fade with transparent section is not.

Comment: could you elaborate some more on what problem you're facing right now? It seems pretty easy of a task and it also seems the you got it working

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to create a Drawable that cuts out a section of a shape programmatically. For the shape I'm currently using a shape in a xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you have the original image in an `ImageView` on top of it place 4 views which are partially dimmed and that's it! 
With some basic math you can know the sizes for each view, and using `RelativeLayout` will allow you to easily place them on the screen.

Good Luck!

P.S. I've attached a sketch to illustrate what I'm suggesting.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a far more efficient approach than what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me after all. It would have if there wasn't other views on the page that had to behave differently. http://gyazo.com/40d47db2d83f9acd0c61c292866a6ca4
There are other views in the background that need to be faded out which is why I was looking at the FrameLayout's Foreground property with Porterduff.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I don't see how having more or less views affects your issue. as long as you keep the four views on top everything else then you'll have your desired effect. Try placing the four "dimmed" views in a layout so that you'll ever have to deal with one element (for animations, visibility and so on). Good luck

Comment: I modified my tests slightly and it turns out this is functional & the correct answer! Sorry haha :) Thanks again.